# Equality relating $L^2$ convergence and martingales

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

I am baffled with this question:

Let $(B_t)$ be a standard Brownian motion. For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions defined by

$$ f_n(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
      |x| & , &  \, &|x| \geq \frac{1}{n}\\
       \frac{n}{2} x^2 + \frac{1}{2n} & , & \, & |x| < \frac{1}{n}.     \end{array}
   \right. $$

Assuming that $(f_n)$ satisfies 
$$ M^{f_n}_t := f_n (B_t) - f_n(0) - \int_0^t \frac{1}{2} f_n''(B_s) \,ds \quad \text{ is a martingale}  \quad \quad \text{ (A)}$$

and

$$ \mathbb{E}\bigg[ |M^{f_n}_t |^2 \bigg] = \int_0^t \mathbb{E} \bigg( |f_n' (B_s) |^2 \bigg) \,ds, \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{(B)} $$
show that there exists a continuous martingale $(M_t)$ such that 
$$ \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \sup_{0 \leq s \leq t}  |M^{f_n}_s - M_s |^2 \bigg] \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$$
and hence
$$ \int_0^t \bigg( n \mathbf{1}_{ \{ |B_s| < \frac{1}{n} \} } \bigg) \,ds \rightarrow |B_t| - M_t \quad \text{as } n \rightarrow \infty \quad  \text{ a.s.}$$

$\mathbf{\text{My progress:}}$

Assuming the existence of $(M_t)$, I applied the Doob's $L^2$- inequality to conclude that
$$ \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \sup_{0 \leq s \leq t}  |M^{f_n}_s - M_s |^2 \bigg] \leq 2 \mathbb{E} \bigg[  |M^{f_n}_t - M_t |^2 \bigg].$$
Then, by (A) and (B), I get (for $n$ large, since $f_n$ converges to $|x|$ uniformly)
$$ \mathbb{E} \bigg[  |M^{f_n}_t - M_t |^2 \bigg] \leq \frac{1}{2} +t -\frac{1}{n} + \mathbb{E} \bigg[ M^2_t +  M_t- 2 M_t |B_t| \bigg]. $$

How can I proceed from here to prove the two facts? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that $(M^{f_n})_{n \geq 0}$ is a Cauchy-sequence with respect to the norm

$$\|M\| := \left(\mathbb{E}\left( \sup_{s \leq t} |M_s|^2 \right) \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Since the space of continous martingales endowed with $\|\cdot\|$ is complete, this proves the claim. In order to show that $(M_t^{f_n})_{n \geq 0}$ is a Cauchy sequence, use that $f_n-f_m$ does also satisfy (A), (B) for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Are you sure that this method works? I get $\mathbb{E} [ |M_t^{ \{f_n -f_m \} } |^2 ] = \frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{m^2}{2n^2} + \frac{(n-m)^2}{2n^2}$, for $n>m$.

Comment: Also, how can we show the second inequality? (The one on a.s. convergence) Are there any results that relate L^p convergence to a.s. convergence that I can apply?

Comment: @erik Yes, I am sure about this. If the sequence is convergent (as you claim), it has to be a Cauchy sequence. Are you sure that there is no mistake in your calculations?

Comment: I am skeptical whether $f_n -f_m$ even satisfies (B), since (B) is not a linear relationship.

Comment: @erik Do you know Itô's formula?